# How to add an array in Interrface Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, interface, ionic3

I have one Interface that contain one array,
this contain of the array provide of other interface.
The problem is that this is the qualitatLlet in not taiking the interface ExcelData properly
The console.log(CIB1, vaca.qualitatLlet) the vaca.qualitatLlet is not showing nothing  and  the Array is always empty, i wrote data by defalut but still showing empty array

```
export interface Vaca {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  CIB: string;

  qualitatLlet: Array<ExcelData>
} 
export interface ExcelData{
  Celules: string;
  ExtracteSec: number;
  CIB: string;
  }

export class DataService {

 private data=[];
  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {
   }
 updateVaca(vaca: Vaca, excel: ExcelData) {
   const CIB1 = vaca.CIB    
  function update(vaca: ExcelData, data, CIB){
    for (let d in data){
      for (let d2 in data[d]){
        if(d2 =="CIB"){
          if(data[d]["CIB"] === CIB){
             vaca.Celules = data[d]["Celules"] 
             vaca.ExtracteSec  = data[d]["ExtracteSec"
        } 
        return data[d]
      }
      }
  }
}
  update(excel, this.data, CIB1);
  console.log(CIB1, vaca.qualitatLlet)
  const vacaDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `vaca/${vaca.id}`);
  console.log(this.data) 
  return updateDoc(vacaDocRef, { nom: vaca.name, CIB: vaca.CIB,  qualitatLlet: vaca.qualitatLlet });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your error message ?

Comment: The   console.log(CIB1, vaca.qualitatLlet) the vaca.qualitatLlet is not showing nothing

Comment: And the Array is always empty, i wrote data by defalut but still showing empty array

Comment: Where do you enter the default data? You declared data as an empty array. Within the `update` function, you're looping over this empty array, which actually doesn't do anything. And what triggers your `updateVaca` function?